# How do you obtain data from database using the current session?

Tags: php, session-variables

Just a question, how do you obtain the data that is already stored in the current session?

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION['member_first_name']

?>
```

Does not display, however,

```
<?php

echo $_SESSION['member_id']

?>
```

displays the current id!

Comment: have you checked that `member_first_name` is set? remember your closin semi-colon `;`

Comment: did you assign the both of them in your page?

Comment: @Sunshines: Those values only contain what you (once) put into them.

Comment: @Lawrence. It's not necessary when it's last command before closing ?> [demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/50811.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you start session

```
session_start();
```

make sure you set that variable

```
<?php
$_SESSION['member_first_name'] = "some_first_name";
echo $_SESSION['member_first_name'];
?>
```

^^ it works [here is demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/89f50.php)

Comment: Thank you so much, so it pretty much works the same as $_POST actually! :) Thanks so much.